# How to make variable infront of pipeline in bash?

Tags: bash, variables, pipeline

I would like to save output of first command as variable in front of pipeline and send them to the pipe, too.

For example: `find -type d | grep -E '^\./y'`. And in my variable going to be output of `find -type d`.

Thanks for help

EDIT
Maybe I can solve this problem another way, but I am standing in front of another problem. How to call my own function with parameter from pipeline?

EX: `find -type d | MyFunction`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RE:

```
EDIT Maybe I can solve this problem another way, but I am standing in front of another problem. How to call my own function with parameter from pipeline?

EX: find -type d | MyFunction
```

The following all work:

```
$ cat ./blah.sh
#!/bin/bash
function blah {
        while read i; do
                echo $i
        done
}    
find ~/opt -type d | blah
blah <<< $(find ~/opt -type d)
blah < <(find ~/opt -type d)

$ ./blah.sh
/home/me/opt
/home/me/opt/bin
/home/me/opt /home/me/opt/bin
/home/me/opt
/home/me/opt/bin
```

So I'd imagine if `find -type d | MyFunction` doesn't work, then the function is probably not looking for input on stdin.

Comment: should be `MyFunction < <(find -type d)` -- that's process substitution

Comment: yeah.. i forgot $() when i wrote that.  long day :/

Comment: I'm not sure, why originally MyFunction doesn't work (I didn't have it in while). Thank you, your solvent works well, but now I've got new problem. I need to test output of grep -q (if name of the dir matches with RE), but there is mistake in syntax.


`1] MyFunction () {
2] while read i; do
3]  if [ { echo $i | grep -E -q '^\./y' }]
4] then
5]  echo $i
6] fi
7] done `

BASH: line 3: [: missing ]'

//I'm sorry, but I'm here new and I don't knew how to separate every line. But every `number]` means new line.

Comment: try `if [ grep -E -q '^\./y' <<< $i ]; then`.  Grep exit code is based on if it finds a match, so you can evaluate your if-statement on that.  The `<<< $i` is just serving grep `$i` as input.

Comment: I've got problem with the redirection again... I've tried `echo $PIPESTATUS` but, when I run the code, there is just empty line. Is there any other way, how to detect Exit code?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily capture the output of any command in a variable using the $() (used to be `) syntax, like this:

VARIABLE=$(command)

You could then just pipe the output of "echo $VARIABLE" into the next command.

However, please keep in mind that the length of the values of shell variables is restricted and not guaranteed to be large enough to hold arbitrary values -- in general, it isn't a good idea to try what you are attempting.

Comment: What shell limits the contents of a variable to 1024 chars?

Comment: I agree with you that it isn't good idea therefore, cause it's not my goal to save whole output of the command, but just one line at the time.

Comment: @Andrew, what do you mean that you don't want the whole output?

Comment: I mean that if you process the _(find . -type d)_ through pipeline, you are handling just one line at the time, but putting the whole output of find and then processing it isn't very efficient.

Comment: @glennjackman: bourne shell and csh on older unixes limited it. It isn't that small in modern shells, but I don't think you're portably allowed to assume more. Unfortunately, opengroup.org is down at the moment or I'd confirm and quote chapter and verse. If I'm wrong, we'll know when it comes back up.

Comment: Okay, The Bible says: "The values that the environment variables may be assigned are not restricted except that they are considered to end with a null byte and the total space used to store the environment and the arguments to the process is limited to {ARG_MAX} bytes" -- ARG_MAX must be at least _POSIX_ARG_MAX which is 4096.

Comment: So, not a limit of 1024 to any given variable any more, but you aren't guaranteed that the total size of the environment is going to be large enough for anything of substantial length. This is of course only what you can portably assume -- in many OSes you can go much larger, but it gets to be a bad habit... I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Andrew's comments to Perry, perhaps

```
find . -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d "" dir; do
  # do something with $dir
  case "$dir" in
    ./y*) echo "$dir" ;;
    *) : ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: I don't understand your solvent at all, so I pasted and tried it. However, bash answer was Illegal option -d. So I erased it and now its answer is "read: 104: : bad variable name" even after renamed $dir.

Comment: The `-d` option to `read` is a bash extension, not available in more basic shells.  What shell are you actually using?

Comment: @Gordon Davisson: GNU bash, verze 4.2.10(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 0):

You can feed variables like this in a array with bash, without any loop :

```
$ read -a array <<< $(find 2>/dev/null -type d | grep -E 'test_[0-9]+')

$ echo ${array[@]} 
./test_003.t ./test_002.t ./test_001.t

$ echo ${array[1]} 
./test_002.t
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried it in a rush, but your solvent works!
I gonna test it in the afternoon ;)

Comment: Your code is great, however it works only on one of our servers... :(
Syntax error: redirection unexpected
Is there something else what can I do?